# Referring domain with bounce rate in SiteCatalyst?

Tags: analytics, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

Long time GA user but new SC user. I want to see a breakdown of referring domain together with bounce rate. When I go to Traffic Sources > Referrer Types  and breakdown other websites by referring domain, I'm not able to add any metrics?

I keep running in to this where I'm in a report view and expect to be able to just add a column but there's nothing available...am I missing something? What's the easiest way to check bounce rate (and other metrics like time on site etc) by referring domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Kookbot alluded to, the native reports are somewhat limited in what metrics are available for them, what you can break them down by, etc..

The best thing you can do is write some code to populate a `prop` and `eVar` with the referring domain on the page, on first page view. props and eVars are much more flexible with adding metrics and breaking things down with (or by).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Adobe Analytics help doc, the only metrics available for this report are "Unique Visitors" and "Instances" (http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/reference/reports_ref_types.html).

If you try and run this report in Report Builder or Data Warehouse, you will experience into the same limitations.

In Ad Hoc reporting, you can add various metrics to the "Referrer Types" dimension